# Cannot send SMS with SIM900 GSM module

Tags: arduino, gsm, c++, sim900

I have a little problem using GSM SIM900 module connected to the Arduino the call is working alright but it doesn't send me SMS I don't know why. This is my code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial SIM900(2, 3);


void setup()
{
  SIM900.begin(9600);
  SIM900power();  
  delay(20000);  // give time to log on to network. 
}

void SIM900power()
// software equivalent of pressing the GSM shield "power" button
{
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);
  delay(5000);
}

void sendSMS()
{
  SIM900.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");                                                        // AT command to send SMS message
  delay(100);
  SIM900.println("AT + CMGS = \"00201155706922"
  "");                                     // recipient's mobile number, in international format
  delay(100);
  SIM900.println("Hello, world. This is a text message from an Arduino Uno.");        // message to send
  delay(100);
  SIM900.println((char)26);                       // End AT command with a ^Z, ASCII code 26
  delay(100); 
  SIM900.println();
  delay(5000);                                     // give module time to send SMS
  SIM900power();                                   // turn off module
}

void loop()
{
    sendSMS();
  do {} while (1);
}
```

Comment: The line where you give the mobile number seems odd and there should not be spaces in the command. Also after the number you have to wait for the module to respond with `>` before sending the message body.

Comment: Have you check your sim card sending sms to this number through your cell phone?

Comment: use this "mySerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+91xxxxxxxxxx\"\r");" where +91 is country code xxxxxxxxxx is you mob number.

Comment: i tried the same code for call but it worked

Comment: You mean the same number format? Please fix the `AT+CMGS=\"+91xxxxxxxxxx\"\r"` line. Either using + or 00 format.

Comment: I tried it bro still not working

Comment: bence kaulics yes i meant so

Comment: `(1)` Baud rate `9600` - is it really so? By default SIM900/800 use `115200`.
`(2)` After send `"AT+CMGS=..."` you must wait for invite `"> "`, so if you don't want to handle it - try to increase delay after this command (about 1-3 seconds, **up to 1 minute according to spec**).